# google nearby connection access to api

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-nearby

I have a problem with the last update of the google nearby connections API.
When I call start `Discovery ()` or start `Advertising ()` before the update I needed to pass a googleApiClient as a parameter.

After the update, I don't need to do this, but I still need to access the api with googleApiClient.

How can I run the sample without using googleApiClient?

```
  private void startAdvertising() {
  Nearby.getConnections(context).startAdvertising(
          getUserNickname(),
          SERVICE_ID,
          mConnectionLifecycleCallback,
          new AdvertisingOptions(STRATEGY))
      .addOnSuccessListener(
        new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(Void unusedResult) {
            // We're advertising!
          }
        })
      .addOnFailureListener(
        new OnFailureListener() {
          @Override
          public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            // We were unable to start advertising.
          }
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Nearby.Connections` instead of `Nearby.getConnections`.

Comment: thank you for the answer.
I did that before the last update and it worked because i put the GoogleApiClient as a parameter of the startAdvertising function.
But after the update as you see in the sample, i dont need the GoogleApiClient and the sample is not working without the GoogleApi Client in order to access the Nearby Api.

Comment: It should be noted that the documentation incorrectly lists `getConnections` as a valid method

Answer (score 1):

Use `Nearby.getConnectionsClient(Context)`, to use the API without making a GoogleApiClient.